# building calculator with complex behavior (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator, solver

i need to build a calculator. The input is a textarea and the behavior is a little complex, it should be like on this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tR5tyhPmawE , `0:00 - 0:30` part. But im a little confuse where to start, im building basic interface and input. Can you point me in the right directions, im just dont know how to manage multilines wise. Thank you.

Comment: kinda, problem that im must using textarea for input and can't understand how to manage lines...

Comment: on every key dow you split the value of the text area by `\n` this will give you an array of lines, then you parse each line and convert to a mathematical equation, each line would probably be grouped into a single sum and use for line line 2, that then would be summed and used in Line 3 etc etc

Comment: thanks a lot, im starting to implement this right now, but still open for another solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that will help you get started.

I quickly wrapped up a sample demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/3tCep/

you can view the source here: https://github.com/davidnorth/JsReckoner

Comment: hahahah, you quickly do that... im spent on it near 4 hours already, nice skills! thanks

Comment: work around with code in the google chrome, than try it in firefox, and it's doesn't work, can you giove me an advice what can cause this(im trying yr clean code from git and it not working via firefox 3.6.16) in google chrome all looks and work fine. thanks

Comment: That's not my code sire, that is code thatI have found for the purpose of helping you, I believe the owner of the git hub page is the developer.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript already provides the functionality via [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp). But you need to strip out any non-numeric chars and perform a currency type rounding on the operations.

If you want interactive operations, then look for a newline char with the [onkeyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) handler.

Comment: would it not be better to build a parser that would covert them to intergers and the switch on the operation character, then place them in calculation sets... `evel`, does not seem like a good solution here.